# SQL joins without duplicate parent rows

Tags: sql, join

I have a one to many relationship in a SQL server database of one x to many ys.

When I join the two tables I will get data like:

```
1x 1x 1y 1y
1x 1x 2y 2y
```

I get the x data twice because there are two children rows associated with it.

The problem is that I need to run a sum on columns that are in both tables and in each case I want to sum on each unique rows column only once. Therefore I would want data like:

```
1x   1x   1y 1y
null null 2y 2y
```

I understand that this could be done with subqueries quite easily but there are performance considerations involved.

Thanks.

Edit -

Since everyone wants a more concrete example:

There is a very large table of orders placed to some kind of shop.
These orders can have discounts. A discount can be applied to multiple orders.
Each order has a tax, shipping, and discount total column at the top level.
Each order has a collection of children order items. These order items have the item price and quantity sold.

For each discount I want the total sales.
This would be the sum of the each order placed with the discounts taxes + the sum of each order placed with each discounts shipping + the sum of each orders order items price * quantity - the sum of the discount total.

So I have two levels that need to be summed. The ones on the orders and the ones on the order items.

The tables cannot be modified.

I have gotten correct numbers with subqueries but I also have to have sorting on the summation columns and I found it to be very slow.

My current model groups by the discount applied and joins the orders and the order items. It is very efficient but returns duplicates of the order columns where they have more than 1 child.

Comment: Don't know about other DBMSs, but MySQL supports `COUNT(DISTINCT somefield)` so you don't count the dupes.

Comment: The fields might not be distinct (apart from the id)

Comment: If you need to run sums on these columns, without any other constraints, why are you joining them together in a single query at all? If there *are* further constraints, please add them to the question.

Comment: I join them for speed reasons. Using subqueries on these tables results in runtimes of ~5 minutes which unacceptable for most users.

Comment: I think you're missing the point (or maybe I am). If we could have a concrete example or two (including sample data and expected results), we may be able to suggest solutions; joins, in and of themselves, don't provide performance boosts/speed increases.

Comment: "sample data and expected results" - you're still describing things at a high level, whereas giving a set of table definitions, insert statements, and expected results would let use build actual queries (even if the table names need modifying) and verify them against the expected results. The extended narrative isn't helping (me).

Comment: Also, if you have an existing slow query, please post that also - we may be able to transform that into a better query with little knowledge of the database.

Answer (score 3):

If subqueries can return the desired result, you should use it.

It always depends on your database structure and requirement. It is not always necessary that sub query will add overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Put it simply, you want to compute the sum total cost of each order, and then sum the total cost of all orders grouped by discount.

```
with orderTotals as (
select discountID,
       min(tax + shipping - discount) + sum(price * quantity) as total
  from orders
  join items on orders.orderID = items.orderID
 group by discountID, orders.orderID
)
select discountID,
       sum(total) as total
  from orderTotals
 group by discountID
;
```

You could substitute max() or avg() for min() and still get the same result, since the tax, shipping, and discount are a constant for a given order.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't include `tax`, `shipping`, `discount` in `group by`. Also, `orderID` in `group by` must be specified together with either of the two table aliases. (Actually, for clarity, I would add the corresponding table name to every column name in your CTE.)

Comment: You are absolutely correct about orderID in group by (fixed), and adding table name to every column is never a bad idea. Including tax, shipping and discount in group by may be more efficient, I don't know.